# Ссылка добавления сайта в социальные сети

Tags: jquery, html, php, css, javascript

Как сделать такую ссылку так

```
<a href="http://vkontakte.ru"></a>
```

чтобы по нажатию на нее открывалось окно, где предлагается добавить закладку в     социальный сервис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда после вопроса до ответа додумываешься сам. Вот собственно, что мне и нужно было:

```
<a href="http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=http://домен.ком/"></a>
```